# Implement view like view pager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-view

Hi I want to implement `view` like `viewpager`, which I want to put in List such that each element can be swiped,

Please refer Below diagram [image]

Here `View 1` and `View 3` will be not visible on swiping right view1 will be visible just like view pager.

I tried using `viewFlicker` but it don't show hidden view on swipe.

To implement this I thought to use `Viewpager` source, [Viewpager.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) its basically `ViewGroup` but view Group I cant add to ListView. I tried [swipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) that also didn't help.

Could any one help me how to implement it

Comment: is the no of screen(main view) is dynamic

Comment: no i ask about the \ main views(view1,view2,view3)

Comment: thats fixed, only 3 views

Comment: so its easy use this external lib https://github.com/TangKe/SlideMenu

Comment: its has three main view u can use list view in this view

Comment: thank u, but its list view. U saying create that view using that library in my adapter ?

Comment: so u want three views in a each row of list. wright ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56109/discussion-between-nithinlal-and-sharanabasu-angadi).

Comment: +1 for the drawing! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest few things do check it out if it works for you :)

1. Create normal view pager as you have done.eg view 1 , 2, and 3.
2. Then, add fragment in view 2 which will consist of custom listview.
3. Then, use getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount methods while using
   listview base adapter for creating different view in same listview.
4. Then, Add view pager as one of the view layout in that listview as
   an item of listview.

I hope you can get little idea. :)